# ICS attachment invite shows up as deleted in GMX.de

Tags: python, icalendar

We are sending booking confirmation emails for events using Django/Python. For this we create an ICS attachment (see below). For some recipients the invite show up as "deleted" when using GMX.de. Does anybody know why and how to fix it?

[image]

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:pyICSParser
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/Berlin
X-LIC-LOCATION:Europe/Stockholm
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
TZNAME:CEST
DTSTART:20230912T193000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=-1SU
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
TZNAME:CET
DTSTART:20230912T193000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=10;BYDAY=-1SU
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20230912T193000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20230912T204500
DTSTAMP:20230912T074825
ORGANIZER;CN=OURCOMPANY:mailto:info
 @OURCOMPANY.de
UID:FIXMEUID20230912T074825
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-    PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;RSVP=TRUE
 ;CN=hallo@OURCOMPANY;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:
 mailto:hallo@OURCOMPANY.de
CREATED:20230912T074825
DESCRIPTION:1x Package Name
LAST-MODIFIED:20230912T074825
LOCATION:Address Street, Somewhere
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Yoga Fortgeschritten
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```